# Flutter application when calling an Android native code generates: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, channel

I am trying to implement ZenDesk on my App Flutter.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import zendesk.support.request.RequestActivity;
import zendesk.core.Zendesk;
import zendesk.support.Support;


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false)
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
      super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
      MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "zen_desk_channel").setMethodCallHandler {
        call, result ->
          if (call.method == "openZenDeskChat") {
            initZenDesk()
          } else {
            result.notImplemented()
          }
      }
    }
    

    private fun initZenDesk() {
      Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(this, "url",
        "app_id",
        "o_auth_client_id")
      Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE)
      openZenDeskChat()
    }

    private fun openZenDeskChat() {
       RequestActivity.builder().show(context);
    }

    
}
```

```
dependencies {
    def appcompat_version = "1.6.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    // For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support', version: '5.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.zendesk.belvedere2:belvedere:3.0.5'
}
```

This is my versions of Flutter and Android

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.1)
```

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.flowing/zendesk.support.request.RequestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in br.com.flowing:layout/zs_activity_request: Binary XML file line #13 in br.com.flowing:layout/zs_activity_request: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

I have already downgraded the material according to the recommendations, I inserted the stylesv31 file for android 12, but it cannot recognize this AppBarLayout of the Material

Comment: Yes @AnkeetKarki.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".{nameApp}.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```